# TypeError: Cannot find function getSheets in object - looking for what's wrong

Tags: google-sheets

While running this code, there is error while executing this line:

```
var invoiceSheet = newSSFile.getSheets()[0];'
```

"TypeError: Cannot find function getSheets in object Copy of Invoice Przykładowy. (line 69, file "Code")"

With this code I want:

1. Create a new spreadsheet and move it to proper folder [works]
2. Get a value from another spreadsheet and paste it in this new one [error]

Looked for answer for an hour without any result. Any idea what might cause this error?

```
function invoice() {

//Create copy SS + name
var ssTemp = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1Cr2W_4lNrHYRdXK-KDQ7UFJJ3Iagh-tGct8Ee5Y");
var newSS = ssTemp.copy("Copy of " + ssTemp.getName());
// Move to folder
var DestinyFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("0B-y1OC8ChG2XRjRRbEJ");
var newSSFile = DriveApp.getFileById(newSS.getId()); 
DestinyFolder.addFile(newSSFile);
DriveApp.getRootFolder().removeFile(newSSFile); 


// Modify details
// Invoice No  
var klienciSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById("18B151VlJaVtDdQ9CcLrL3iwRAtWw2ZzZydproj");
var klienciSheet = klienciSS.getSheets()[0];
var klienciRange= klienciSheet.getRange('AB6');
var klienciValue = klienciRange.getValue(); 
var invoiceSheet = newSSFile.getSheets()[0];
var inboiceRange = invoiceSheet.getRange('F4'); 
newCellInvoice.setValue(klienciValue);
```

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to achieve. One can only guess that you are trying to do something with Google Drive and Spreadsheets but unless you provide some more details, no one will answer your question.

Comment: 1. Create a new spreadsheet and move it to proper folder [works]

2. Get a value from another spreadsheet and paste it in this new one [error]

Comment: Please take a look to [ask] and more specifically to [mcve] (The code isn't complete).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by the following line

```
var newSSFile = DriveApp.getFileById(newSS.getId());
```

It makes that newSSFile holds an instance of [Class File](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file) instead of an instance of [Class Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet)

But the problematic line looks unnecessary. Replace the line that throws the error by

```
var invoiceSheet = newSS.getSheets()[0];
```